# Trouble with global.asax routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

I have some links in my webapp that looks like this:

```
localhost:12345/?something=1
localhost:12345/?something=2
localhost:12345/?something=3
localhost:12345/?something=4
```

each number at the end is an id that i need to pass to my controller to display information related to it.

I know I need to create a new `routes.MapRoute` in my `global.asax` page, but I am not really quite sure how to go about it. I tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Id", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{*Id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Id", Id = "" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

**---EDIT---**

I am only successful getting each individual like to display by doing the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "IdRoute", // Route name
    "{Id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1 } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This does work, however, this only works for one id (specifically 1). I am not quite sure how to go about this, but i need i need:

```
localhost:12345/?something=1
```

to display the information for id 1,

```
localhost:12345/?something=2
```

to display the information for id 2,

```
localhost:12345/?something=3
```

to display the information for id 3.

I there are going to be hundreds of ids so hard coding something in would not be a convenient option. I have had no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            "RootName",
            "{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1 });
```

This will produce links like this localhost/1
If you want this kind of links localhost/?id= 1
Then :

```
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            "RootName",
            String.Empty,
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});


public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        //do something with id, make query to database whatever

        // u usually have model class so you would fill model with your data
        var model = new YourModel();
        //...
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to semi-work. The only issue with your code is that you only have it working for the first id. Would you know of a way that I would be able to pass any of the ids through? There are going to be hundreds of ids and it would be a pain to have to write it in each time.

Comment: Hmm, you want an Id to be an action, ah hmm why don't you use one action and pass id as param to that action.

Comment: That is what this routes are doing.

Comment: Since I have never really had to work with routing or using the global.asax page before, i do not really quite understand..

Comment: Sorry wasn't near stackoverflow, can you please add your controller code, so i can understand what are you looking to do. In general this looks to me like you are trying to pass and id as a parameter, parameter are passed to action methods in controller. That action method takes that parameter and does what ever you need to do with it. If so than just make one controller action method named whatever replace "Index" with that name and you can work on that param in your action method. I have edited the code to show you how that action would look.

Comment: I ended up working through the issue my self. It just changed the way that I was calling my Id in the link to the appropriate format and that seemed to work just fine. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have following Action in, say, HomeController:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int Id)
    {
        return View()
    }
```

You may use any of following routes:

```
//* For Id = 3 this will return path "Home/SomeAction/3" 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "First",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SomeAction", Id= UrlParameter.Optional}
            );


//* For Id = 3 this will return path "SomeAction/3" 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "First",
                url: "{action}/{Id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SomeAction", Id= UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

//* For Id = 3 this will return path "Home/SomeAction(3)" 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "First",
                url: "{controller}/{action}({Id})",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SomeAction", Id= UrlParameter.Optional}
            );


//* For Id = 3 this will return path "LadyGaga/SomeAction/3" 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "First",
                url: "LadyGaga/{action}/{Id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SomeAction", Id= UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```